# Closing Excel UserForm on CommandButton click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a ListBox. The sheet code has a ListBox_DblClick sub that launches UserForm1. UserForm1.CommandButton1 launches UserForm2. The user may input data in UserForm2 then press UserForm2.CommandButton1 which launches a sub in a module (yet to be written) and closes UserForm2.

With the code below, both UserForm2 and UserForm1 close. I just want UserForm2 to close upon click of UserForm2.CommandButton1.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong are appreciated.

UserForm2 code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call UpdateBids(TextBox1.Object.Value, TextBox2.Object.Value, ComboBox1.Object.Value)
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your full code - even better can you post your workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon researching this again, I stumbled upon this post:
[Why, after launching a userform from a userform, does unloading the 2nd userform close both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232235/why-after-launching-a-userform-from-a-userform-does-unloading-the-2nd-userform)

In short it suggested closing Excel then adding DoEvents following UserForm2.Show.  It worked.  Now only my UserForm2 closes.  I've not had the problem since.